# reshape list to (-1,1) and return float as datatype

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to build Logistic Regression model, data.Exam1 is the first column

```
    reg = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
    X = list(data.Exam1.values.reshape(-1,1)).........(1)
```

I have performed this operation

```
type(X[0]) returns numpy.ndarray
```

reg.fit accepts parameters which contains all float items in the list, so I did this because of this exception `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'`

```
newX = []
for item in X:
    type(float(item))
    newX.append(float(item))
```

so when I tried to do

```
reg.fit(newX,newY,A)
```

It throws me this exception

```
Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

which I already did in (1), and when I try to reshape again it returns ndarray again, how can I have reshape and convert items to float simultaneously??
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `.reshape(-1, 1).astype(float)`?  See reference [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)

Comment: @wflynny Tried this `X = list(data.Exam1.values.reshape(-1,1).astype(float))` just now, still returned ndarray

Comment: @wflynny it returns (100,)

Comment: @wflynny Still failed :( , I attached an image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136192/discussion-between-wflynny-and-mrrobot9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adapting our solution from chat*

You are trying to understand Admission (type: bool) as a function of Exam scores (Exam1: float, Exam2: float).  The crux of your issue is that `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` expects two inputs:

- `X`: a vector/matrix of training data with the shape (number of observations, number of predictors) with type float
- `Y`: a vector of categorical outcomes (in this case binary) with the shape (number of observations, 1) with type bool or int

They way you are calling it is trying to fit Exam2 (float) as a function of Exam1 (float).  This is the fundamental issue.  Further complicating matters is the way you are recasting your reshaped numpy array as a list.  Assuming `data` is a `pandas.DataFrame`, you want something like:

```
X = np.vstack((data.Exam1, data.Exam2)).T 
print X.shape # should be (100, 2) 
reg.fit(X, data.Admitted)
```

Here, both `data.Exam1` and `data.Exam2` are vectors of length 100.  Using `np.vstack` combines them into the shape (2, 100), so we take the transpose so that we have it oriented properly with observations along the first dimension (100, 2).  No need to recast as list or even take `data.Exam1.values` as the `pd.Series` gets recast as `np.array` during `np.vstack`.  Similarly, `data.Admitted` (with shape (100,)) plays nicely with `reg.fit`.